# Force Desktop OneDrive to Prompt for Password

Tags: windows-8, security, passwords, virus, onedrive

I use the Windows 8 implementation of "Desktop OneDrive" to create and access files stored in my OneDrive account. My OneDrive login is also my Windows login so that when I'm using my computer all my OneDrive directories are immediately available through Windows Explorer and I do not need to enter a password to access them.

**Is there a way to force Windows to require a password to access these files?**

My concern is that if my computer were to be hit with a virus (I'm thinking about Ransom-Ware), all my OneDrive files are accessible on the file system. If OneDrive prompted me for a password each time I used them they would not be vulnerable.

Comment: Just saying why keep sensitive files on OneDrive